# Anylogic: How to add costs (per route) per time of day?

Tags: database, routes, simulation, anylogic

I have data on different costs per route per time of day for container transport (e.g., from zone A to zone B in the morning; the total costs of transport are 100 euros), for almost 200 zones with 4 times of day. How can I assign these costs in my Anylogic model per route **per time of day**?

(after this I would like agents (trucks) to decide (based on the costs) which route and time of day to travel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given no example data I am using some made-up data to give you an example of how to do this.

Suppose I have the following route and cost data

[image]

[image]

You can import this into the AnyLogic DB and then use them to populate a custom class with your data.

For example here is a custom Java class for your routes

```
public class MyRoute {
    String id;
    String from;
    String to;
    
    LinkedHashMap<String, Double> routeCosts = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
    
    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public MyRoute(String id, String from, String to) {
        this.id = id;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    
    public void addCost(String timeOfDay, double cost) {
        routeCosts.put(timeOfDay, cost);
    }
}
```

And then I have a little function to populate them from the DB

```
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(routes).list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
    MyRoute route = new MyRoute(
        row.get( routes.route ),
        row.get( routes.from_db ),
        row.get( routes.to_db )
    );
    
    // Add costs
    List<Tuple> costRows = selectFrom(costs)
    .where(costs.route.eq(route.id))
    .list();

    for (Tuple costRow : costRows) {
        route.addCost(
            row.get( costs.time_of_day ), 
            row.get( costs.cost )
        );
    }   
}
```

Now you can sort the routes based on the costs or time of day and use this to make your decisions

You can see more on sorting here https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashmap-sort

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! When implementing it I only got an error from the last scentence: `myRoutes.add(route);` It says: _"myRoutes cannot be resolved"_, (and it also doesn't work when I change it to _MyRoute_).. Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry! I had a myRoutes collection on my main where I added the routes created to check them. Will edit answer